# How to convert a $size variable from bytes into GB in Powershell?

Tags: variables, powershell, size, byte, converters

In Powershell, I would like to convert $size variable from bytes into GB gigabytes. What is the best way to do it? 
So far I have the following script:

```
$dir = "C:\Users\student"
$count = @{}
$size = @{}
$hostname = @{}
gci $dir -recurse |%{
[int]$count[$_.extension] += 1
[int64]$size[$_.extension] += $_.length
}
$results = @()
$count.keys | sort |% {
$result = ""|select extension,count,size,hostname
$result.extension = $_
$result.count = $count[$_]
$result.size = $size[$_]
$result.hostname = $(get-content env:computername)
$results += $result
}
$results | ft -auto
$results | sort-object -property size -Descending | select-object -first 30| export-csv c:\"$env:computername-$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm)".csv
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

there is a trick for it

```
$result.size = $size[$_] /1Gb
```

and if you want better view for results you can truncate it

```
$result.size = [math]::round($size[$_] /1Gb, 3)
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692684.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I'll add another tip to the Answer from sqladmin.

If the object is stored in byes then `[math]::round($size[$_] /1Gb, 3)` will work.  If it is stored in another unit (*for example, [Database.Size Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.size?view=sqlserver-2016) is in **MB***) then you can multiply it by the unit of measure and divide by GB.  So for MB unit: `@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.size*1MB/1GB,4)}}`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

while you have your basic answer [*grin*], this is a variant way to gather/process/collect/output the info.

it uses the `-AsHashTable` parameter of `Group-Object` to build the extension lookup table. then iterates thru the keys, replaces the blank extension key with a filler name, calcs the file size, builds a `[PSCustomObject]`, and finally sends it out to the collection.

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP

# the "-Force" parameter includes the hidden & system files
#    without = 503 files
#    with    = 535 files
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -File -Recurse -Force

$FileTypesTable = $FileList |
    Group-Object -AsHashTable -Property Extension

$TypeInfo = foreach ($FTT_Item in $FileTypesTable.Keys)
    {
    $Extension = @('_No_Ext_', $FTT_Item)[[bool]$FTT_Item]
    $Size_Bytes = ($FileTypesTable[$FTT_Item].Length |
            Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Extension = $Extension
        Count = $FileTypesTable[$FTT_Item].Count
        Size_GB = [math]::Round($Size_Bytes / 1GB, 4)
        #Size_Bytes = $Size_Bytes
        }
    }

$TypeInfo |
    Sort-Object -Property Size_GB -Descending
```

output ...

```
Extension Count Size_GB
--------- ----- -------
.msi          1  0.2637
.exe         35  0.1568
.wmv          4  0.0978
.mp3         12  0.0647
.log        142  0.0579
.zip          3  0.0454
.jpg         32  0.0217
.csv         67  0.0044
.xpi          1  0.0031
.txt        116  0.0026
_No_Ext_      7  0.0023
.part         1  0.0023
.ico         24  0.0001
.bat         18       0
.m3u8         1       0
.json         1       0
.xls          8       0
.ps1          1       0
.js           1       0
.xml          4       0
.mp4          8       0
.ani          1       0
.ini         25       0
.tmp         21       0
.bmp          1       0
```

Comment: Moving my head, I am thinking of a practical scenario where I could use your lines which group file extensions of a folder and sort the bytes ascending. But to no avail. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Timo - the OP mentioned in a comment that he also wanted to find the amount of storage used per file type. my code does that. it is NOT a solution to the Question ... but is a solution to a sub-question mentioned in a comment. [*grin*] ///// as for a reason to use the above code, if you need to know what file type is gobbling up space ... that will be shown with the stuff i posted.